# How to return the firefox devtools to the bottom of the screen from top

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Developer tools can be displayed in two modes: at the bottom or at the side. But if they are displayed together with firebug, they rise to the top from bottom and then remain there, even if firebug closed or completely removed from Firefox. How to bring devtools back down? I can not find the appropriate setting. It is very undesirable to create new profile.

This behavior is bound to the domain, and even with different paths within one domain devtools may appear at the top or bottom. Current workaround is to find where devtools open at bottom and then go to the desired page and try to never close it.

[image]

[image]